# JSTL doesn't remove variable value

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to clean a list of objects that my JSP File receives, and I execute the following command:

```
<c:remove var="list" scope="session" />
<c:out value="${list}"></c:out>
```

But when I call the JSP page, the page shows the memory address of the list that should have been deleted and fill normally the HTML elements with the attributes of objects that are defined in the list.

**EDIT**

I'm using my own tag, can it influence? Object contains list.

```
<ec:form beanName="object" controllerUrl="/param1/param2">
```

And if I remove the object with:

```
<c:remove var="object">
```

Raises `NullPointerException`

References:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/RemoveVariable.htm

Comment: Maybe the `list` is not stored at the session scope? It's more likely stored at the request scope.

Comment: Which scope does list have?

Answer (score 2):

Here I am not sure in which scope your attribute lives.So i would suggest to
Try this

```
<c:remove var="list"/>
```

This above code removes an attribute from all the scopes (page, session, application, request). In order to be specific we must need to specify the scope attribute inside   tag.The below JSTL statement will remove the variable list from session scope.

```
<c:remove var="list" scope="session"/>
```